# usage of values from resx-files in an extension method

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-core

assuming that i have a .NET MVC (respectively .NET Core) solution with the projects

- MyProject.Web.Website (containing the web layer of my application)
- MyProject.Web.Resources (containing the resx files)
- further projects, e.g. business layer, data access layer etc. (i omitted for brevity)

in MyProject.Web.Website i have an extension method for a model-class where i'd like to use a value from one of the resource files.

which of these two approaches is more correct to keep a clean and correct software architecture?

1. call the value of the resx file directly in the extension method, e.g. MyProject.Web.Resources.MyResource.PleaseSelect
2. pass the value of the resource when i use this extension method (in the controllers of MyProject.Web.Website

Answer (score 1):

As every topic related with architecture and software designs the answer shall be "It depends".

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Let´s talk about a Localization requirement. If you have to support multiple languages then maybe the idea of passong the value of resx file sounds better since this value could vary like this: **resources.en.resx**, **resources.de.resx**, **etc**

But if this is not a requirement then I would choose to use directly the resource from the extension method.

Both alternatives are valid.

Hope this helps